# raster tile - find the correct tile for a given coordinate

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a large raster map which I loaded into postgis with 1000x1000 meter tiles... the corresponding table has about 200 rows, each row representing a tile. I want to get the raster value for a specific coordinate, but I don't know how to do that most efficiently.

I did something like:

```
select ST_Value(rast, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lat lon)',4326),mysrid)) from rasterdata;
```

but it gives me a lot of:

```
Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates:...
```

messages because finally only one tile contains the coordinate that I'm searching for.

Comment: Good reply by nickves, but lat and long seem switched in 'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT()'.

Answer (score 12):

Add a `where` constrain. that way you will make use of postgis powerful gist indexes.

```
select 
     ST_Value(rast, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT((lon lat)',4326),mysrid)) 
from 
     rasterdata 
where
     ST_Intersects(rast,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326),mysrid))
 ;
```

Also if you haven't build the index table yet you can do this way:

`CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometrycolumn] );`

then run VACUUM ANALYSE to populate the index:

`VACUUM ANALYSE rasterdata`

**EDIT:**
Changed the order of params in function [ST_POINT](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html)()  since they are (lon lat) and not the other way around as Franck Theeten noticed above.

Comment: user16794: Can you please mark this answer up, and mark it as "answered"? Thanks.